# Write rewrite rule into .htaccess file using hooks and filters in wordpress plugin development

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to add some rewrite rules in the .htaccess file of the WordPress site by writing code into plugins functions.php by using filter or hooks or function. I have used hook "mod_rewrite_rules" to write some rules but failed.
If that possible?

Comment: How is javascript relevant

Comment: you have to save permalinks settings in order to reflect changes you have made or to flush rewrite rules with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/